# Tag cleanup for app stores

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently we have synonyms as follows:

[image]

There are 1300 questions that will be affected. I propose reversing the order and making appstore a synonym of app-store. I propose making ios-appstore a synonym of app-store.

Answer (score -1):

https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/mac-appstore/synonyms this has ~1000 questions too.

Are you proposing ?

```
Primary   :  app-store    | mac-appstore
Secondary :  ios-appstore |
```

For me

```
Primary   :  ios-appstore | mac-appstore
Secondary :  app-store    |
```

seems better. I'd even support letting app-store die.

Comment: No. I’m not proposing a mac  /iOS split - just reversing the direction

Comment: It would seem better just having one app-store tag since other tags like ios or macos can be used as well.

Comment: Hmm makes sense @RyDev